# ASP.NET MVC (Domain Model, Repository, Fluent, Services - Structure for my Project)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dependencies, project-structure

In my ASP.NET MVC web application, I have:

- Domain Model, created by LINQ to SQL
- Repositories such as

  `UserRepository` and `OrderRepository`
- IQueryable Fluents as IQueryable Extension Methods such as

  `public IQueryable<Order> GetNewOrders(this IQueryable<Order>)`
- Services such as

  `UserService` and `OrderService`
- Utility Classes and Extension Methods such as

  `CryptoUtility` (doing Hashing etc.) and String etc. extensions
- ViewModels which are special for each MVC View
- The ASP.NET MVC project itself (Controllers, Views)

I'm looking for the best project structure/organization for my case, especially separating into different assemblies and how dependencies should look like between these layers. Web resources unfortunately don't go into good detail about this.

One hint: Currently Repository, Services, IQueryable Fluents etc. work directly against domain model implementation, I don't have an interface definition for them. I considered it unnecessary but maybe this is needed for loose coupling? My Services have an interface (e.g. IOrderService), and my repositories implement IRepository<T>.

Appreciate your input on organizing this in a concise manner, and especially what layer should depend on what & assembly organization. Thank you!

Comment: Related post - [Best Structure for ASP.NET MVC Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16455870/465053)

Answer (score 8):

I would look at the article by Jeffrey Palermo on the Onion Architecture [here](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/). This basic architecture works well in any project and will allow you to separate your core project (domain layer, persistence, etc.) from your web project.

We use this with MVC/StructureMap/FluentNHibernate and have had great success.

We end up having a structure similar to the one below.

```
> trunk
  + build (build scripts)
  + lib (external libraries)
  > src (source code)    
   >> Organization.App (solution name)
     >> Organization.App.Core (code library)
        + Config
        > Domain
          > Model
          > Persistence
          > Queries
          > Services
        > Persistence
        > Services
     >> Organization.App.Web (mvc web app)
        > Assets
          + Images
          + Scripts
          + Stylesheets
        + Controllers
        + Views
        + ViewModels
```

That's the basic idea. The web app references the core app for domain entities our repository/unit of work. Check out [this older project on google code](http://code.google.com/p/fsu-isys-489-spring-09-group-2/source/browse/trunk) for a similar example. The great part about this is we have been able to add new "UI" project types to the same solution and re-use our core project as intended. Like a console app or a second web app, or whatever you need.

Comment: Where do you put services? in the Core project?

Comment: You can. I like that to keep the number of dlls we need to build to a minimum. But you could put it in a separate project. I added it to the tree for you. We also have the notion of domain services so those would go under the domain folder/namespace. This would be a service that only works with domain entities though. The services folder you see under the project would be a "application" service in that it might have repositories injected as well as other application services to do work. It depends. :)

Comment: Looks like fsu-isys-489-spring-09-group-2 has been taken down. I can't find where it's gone to. Also, what is the difference between Persistence and Services under Domain versus under the root of the Core project?

Answer (score 3):

A couple of different projects do go in more detail about this (but mind you it also takes some effort to really understand how all the different parts work together)

- [S#arp architecture](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/)
- [Code camp server](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=codecampserver) using [the onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/)
- Rob Connery's [storefront screencast serries](http://blog.wekeroad.com/mvc-storefront/)

Comment: Code camp server is a great example.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [s#arp architecture](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/) to see how they structure things. It uses NHibernate and their repos are kinda directly tied to them so you'll need to modify it.