# An Ideal Folder Structure for .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, naming-conventions, conventions

When I started in .NET Webforms I didn't have much trouble finding a folder structure to follow since VS offered you application folders like "App_Code" and most app examples put "BLL", "DAL" inside there and so on.

But now in MVC, every example I check uses different structure, like no standards this time and I haven't found a good solution on Google or SO.

So, maybe we can share how we organize our MVC projects, may help others to make their own mind. Here is the structure for small to medium projects I use:

```
App_Data
Areas
    Admin
        Controllers
        Models
        Views
    MyAccount
        Controllers
        Models
        Views
Content
    Images
    Scripts
    Styles
Controllers
    HomeController.cs
Helpers
    ExtensionMethods    // I.e. based on HtmlHelper, use "helper" suffix
        MenuHelper.cs    // to be called as html.Menu()
    Utilities.cs    // Other generic (static) libraries, no suffix used
Models
    ViewModels    // for passing models to Views
        RegisterViewModel.cs    // use "ViewModel" suffix
    Customer.cs    // to extend models like adding Model Validation
Repositories
    CustomerRepository.cs    // use "Repository" suffix
Services
    CustomerService.cs    // use "Service" suffix, to move code away from controllers
Views
    Home
        Index.cshtml
        Register.cshtml
    Shared    // Site Layouts (Master templates), also put partials here
        SiteLayout.cshtml
```

What about yours?

Comment: Possibly-noob question: although I've been using ASP.NET MVC for a long time, I've never encountered `.cshtml`! What is that? :)

Comment: Yes, that's razor, the new default view engine on MVC3, is cleaner and makes code more readible, you can check a blog from Scott Gu: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

Comment: It seems this post comes up first on searches for "mvc 4 folder structure", but the question and answers are likely antiquated.  Asp.Net MVC often requires a very strict directory structure.  Anyone know of any updates on an ideal tree?

Comment: The reason you may have not found an "ideal tree" is the reason I posted this: there is not an ideal one, so I suggest we share ours. Everyone sooner or later adopts one of its own. I think is more about making a balance between what MVC needs for conventions (keeping folders like Controllers, Views), adopting common accepted standards (folders for Models, Services), and then adding your own flavor (I now split a solution in projects like MyApp.Core, MyApp.Web, MyApp.Localization).

Comment: Why did [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14623056/good-naming-convention-for-classes-associated-with-an-mvc-app-directory) which is basically the same as this get closed as "not constructive", when this one didn't?

Comment: Related post - [ASP.NET MVC (Domain Model, Repository, Fluent, Services - Structure for my Project)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1349640/465053)

Answer (score 15):

I have found it simplifies deployment to have the website project contain only content (no compiled code).

Something like:

**Web.Site project**

```
   Content
      Images
      Css
   Scripts
   Views
   web.config
```

And move all compiled code into  another project:

**Web project**

```
   Controllers
   Filters
   Models
   ...
```

Then, you can treat everything within the Web.Site project as needing to be deployed, and all required assemblies will be in Web.Site\bin.

Whether you are doing simple xcopy deployment, or using WiX to build an MSI package, this will make life a little easier.

Comment: I second this. My projects are usually organized with a 'Web' project and then a 'Web.Components' project. The 'Web' project has very little code in it, while 'Web.Components' houses all things like Controllers and Filters. Finally, I have a 'Core' project which contains my models.

Comment: Very interesting, yes, I like too, I will consider it for my own projects. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 6):

I second the two project approach. Jimmy Bogard has a [nice post on the approach](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2009/12/08/organizing-asp-net-mvc-solutions.aspx) as well  (make sure to go through all the comments).

I personally find that when I'm working on a part of an application I use related services, controllers, repositories, etc.. and when you put each of these files in a different folder it can get tedious going back and forth and finding them. After some playing around I've been following this format:

**AppName.Web.UI**

```
Scripts
Content
View
```

**AppName.UI.Core**

```
Attributes
Filters
Formatters
Helpers
Models
  Company
     Interfaces
       IController.cs
       IRepository.cs
       IService.cs
     ViewModels
       ViewModel1.cs
       ViewModel2.cs
     Controller.cs
     Repository.cs
     Service.cs
  User
    ....
Plugins (mailchimp, Twitter OAuth, etc..)
Global.asax (define all the code here rather than in the UI project)
```

**Test Project**

```
  ...
```

I think it depends how large your project is as to whether you further break down and use Interface and ViewModel sub folders. Its not perfect, but I've found it meshes better with  the way I think.

The case can also be made to put your services and repositories into a third project (AppName.Core), leaving the AppName.Web.Core project encapsulating only Web relates parts (Attributes, Controllers. ViewModels, etc..). Again that really relates to the complexity of the project.

Comment: I read the post you mention and I have a question for this structure, how to use with Areas? Because the Areas have their own Models, Controllers, Views, and Area controllers are different from Controllers at root, so how to divide this using IU, Core?

Comment: I personally haven't gotten into using areas that much, but you should be able to logically break them down in a similar fashion. I'd add the area to the UI project, and then move the related controller to the Core project. As long as the namespaces are kept the same the physical project structure shouldn't matter. OR, depending on if you want your areas to be re-usable in different projects, you could just have a single project for each area and reference them in your main project.. really depends on what your goal for the different areas are.

Comment: Mr. Bogard no longer seems to favor the two project approach. About a year ago he wrote a comment in the [post](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/12/09/organizing-asp-net-mvc-solutions/#comment-1543081601) you mentioned that says: "Sorry, this post is insanely old and out of date. Just do one project, don't create two projects."

Answer (score 5):

So long as it's clear where things are, it doesn't matter much. I think it's just a matter of being consistent within your organization/group.

Comment: I know, but usually you want to make your standard before starting "serial production" of websites, and you want feel your standard is the best you could figure out. Becuase few consistent examples I spent almost whole day coming out with this, so maybe we can save time to others by sharing our "suggested" structures.

Comment: what do you think about this? http://www.dotnetexpertguide.com/2012/01/dividing-mvc-components-in-separate.html