# ASP.NET MVC UI Project + Core Project Split

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I've seen discussed the MVC project structure using a UI Project and a Code Project. e.g.

http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/12/09/organizing-asp-net-mvc-solutions/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357911/an-ideal-folder-structure-for-net-mvc

I've tried to do this in Visual Web Developer 2010 Express but I still end up having the following non-website related files in the UI project: .csproj, .csproj.user, the project dll file and the project pdb file.

This defeats the purpose, as the point of splitting into two projects was to have the UI one clean enough to run directly as the website without having to filter out un-necessary files.

- I copied the original project into a second project contained within the same solution
- I deleted the code files from the first project making it the UI project
- I deletes the UI files from the second project making it the code project
- I added a reference to the code project in the UI project.

Have I done this wrong? Or is this a limitation of this approach?

Any additional detail which might help me get this configuration working would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for separating a project into separate core + UI projects is to cleanly separate the source code concerns.

Two of the files you are mentioning, the CSPROJ and CSPROJ.USER files, are for VWD only. They are not source code, and are not deployed when you publish your project.

The other 2 files, core DLL and core PDB, are runtime assemblies and debug files respectively. Your UI project will need a reference to these in order to be able to run code written and compiled into the core project.

So, having Core.dll and Cord.pdb in the bin folder of your UI project is okay, and doesn't violate SoC. The csproj files have nothing to do with code, they are only there so that VWD can manage the projects.

Comment: Sorry the DLL/PDB files I was referring to are the UI project which actually has no code but still produces a 3KB DLL.

With regard to the VWD project files, yes I understand, I'm just used to the other way of opening a website project where the project files are stored outside the site.

Comment: If your UI project is an MVC3 project, it does produce code. See the global.asax file. This is compiled into your UI's dll.

Comment: I moved global.asax.cs to the core project meaning its part of the core DLL, leaving only global.asax itself in the UI project which only has the <%@ Application %> line - would that still compile further?

Comment: Further, making a bare bones web application project and removing everything from it (including references and properties) still compiled to a 3KB file which isn't required to run the site. I guess I could set the bin path to be outside the web directory to avoid having the un-necessary DLL. Or just live with it.

Comment: I finally found an example, its looks just like mine - must have done it right then http://derans.blogspot.com/2010/01/aspnet-mvc-sample-project-launched.html